# Show that complex function satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equations at z=1 but is not differentiable there.

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, complex-numbers, cauchy-riemann-equations

Question is here $$f(z) = \frac{|z-1|^4}{(z-1)^3} | (z\neq 1), f(1)=0$$

I have no idea how to partially differentiate a function with $|z-1|^4$ in the numerator and I can't find examples of similar problems with anything other than a final solution that doesn't make much sense.

Any help or first steps would be appreciated.

to show some work, I know that it's required to separate into u(x,y) and v(x,y), but I'm not sure how to separate the real and imaginary portion of the mod|z| without multiplying it all out. if I knew what u and v were I would have a solid grasp of where to go.

Comment: Hint.  Use the "limit" definition for these derivatives.  For example $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(a+ib) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{u(a,b+h)-u(a,b)}{h}$$  Here, I wrote $f(x+iy) = u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ with $u,v$ real-valued.

Comment: Is there a simple way to determine the real and imaginary parts, or do I need to multiply it out. The numerator I believe is $|x+iy-1|^4$ or $((x-1)^2+y^2)^2$ which doesn't seem easy to work with.

Comment: after re-looking over my notes I understand what you mean now. I'll basically be taking the limits at (1,0) along the x or y-axes. The only thing I'm having issues with now is determining what portions of the function are real vice imaginary. The modulus in the numerator can only be real, but the denominator seems very messy. Does that sound correct?

Comment: You will be interested in $z-1$ on the real axis for $\partial/\partial x$ and $z-1$ on the imaginary axis for $\partial/\partial y$.  So $(z-1)^3$ will be easy in all the cases you need.